# How to filter search results with different attributes

Tags: php, search

So I want to have a search page with a filter. For example I would search for a product and filter it by price or by color. With my code here, I want to search for a record that will show according to my filter. In my code, I only have LASTNAME. If I search a lastname that exists on my database, that record will show. The lastname consists of firstname too and age. So I want to add filter options like filter it by age or firstname and not just the lastname. How do I do it? I tried plenty of codes but still confusing. I hope I could get a little help.

```
 <?php

 mysql_connect("localhost","root","") OR die("Could not connect!");
 mysql_select_db("friends") OR die("No database found!"); //"friends"

 $output='';

 if(isset($_POST['search'])){
   $searchq = $_POST['search'];
   $searchq = preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#i","",$searchq);

   $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Names WHERE lastname LIKE '%$searchq%' ") or die("could not           search!");
   $count = mysql_num_rows($query);

   if($count == 0){
   header("Location: error.html");

   }
        else{
   while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){

     echo "<tr>";
     $fname = "<td>".$row['FirstName']."<td>";
     $lname = "<td>".$row['LastName']."<td>";
     $Gender = "<td>".$row['Gender']."<td>";
     $Age = "<td>".$row['Age']."<td>";
     $id = "<td>".$row['id']."<td>";
     echo "<tr>";

     $output .='<div>'.$id.'&nbsp'.$fname.'&nbsp'.$lname.'&nbsp'.$Gender.'&nbsp '.$Age.'</div>';
   }
   }
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "The lastname consists of firstname too and age."?  You should also read on [SQL Injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and MySQL is deprecated (you should use [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php)).

Comment: Please show us what you have tried already. SO is for people to help you with your programming problems, not for them to do the work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
$age = $_POST['Age'];
$first_name = $_POST['FirstsName'];

$filter = "";

if(isset($age)) {
$filter .= " AND Age = '$age'";
}

if(isset($first_name)) {
$filter .= " AND Age = '$first_name'";
}

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Names WHERE lastname LIKE '%$searchq%' {$filter} ") or die("could not           search!");
```